# SQL Case When check for spaces within address

Tags: sql, validation, case

I am trying to ensure that if more than three spaces are entered into an address line then it is flagged, but I am not having any success with this so far. Can somebody tell me how to get around this please? Sorry if this is a daft question.

Here is the code that doesn't validate this (the code I have tried):

```sql
case when c.cAddress1 LIKE '%[ ]%[ ]%[ ]%' 
       THEN 'Data Appears Ok'
     when c.cAddress1 LIKE '%[ ]%[ ]%'
       THEN 'Data Appears Ok'
     when c.cAddress1 LIKE '%[ ]%' 
       THEN 'Data Appears Ok'
     when c.cAddress1 IS NULL
       THEN 'Empty'
     when c.cAddress1 LIKE '%'
       THEN 'Data Appears Ok'
     ELSE 'Check AddressLine1 for Comments'
END as [Addressline1 Comment Validation],
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to get 'Check AddressLine1 for Comments'. Your case returns Empty for NULL, and 'Data Appears Ok' for all non-null vales. Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) A [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you need count of space character use this code and decide if it is valid for you:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Address1 NVARCHAR(1000)
);

INSERT @table
(
    Address1
)
VALUES
('Part1 Part2 Part3 Part4'),
('Part1 Part2 Part3');

SELECT t.Address1, parts.partCount - 1 AS [Space character]
FROM    @table AS t
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(1) partCount FROM STRING_SPLIT(t.Address1, ' ') AS ss) parts
```

Comment: HI Jarlh, I am using MsSQL. First SQL job.

HI Meyssam Toluie, this won't work because it is in a view and your script contains DML commands. Essentially this needs to be without DML commands, I think.

Comment: @Vern this is only a sample. Not the exact answer. DML(s) are used to provide some data. See how it works and  use it in your own query.